# Where to access some statitics

Tags: discussion

I want to know how many questions are asked every day? also How many answers are there in one day. Or how many questions are asked during a month? and some kind of statistics? Is there any way to access them on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic has some information in relation with the rest of the SE network.

Comment: it redirects me to http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Answer (score 1):

- http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic
- [Relevant Meta question on StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180132/236725)