# How to access askubuntu meta data for programmatic statistical analysis?

Tags: support

I wanted to conduct some statistical analysis on certain dimensions relevant to the development of the site and was wondering how to access data in order to construct a data set for that. For example, how would I get data to calculate the correlation between # of edits of questions and their upvotes?

I checked out [Where to access some statitics](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11641/where-to-access-some-statitics) and [Direct access to Askubuntu reputation statistics](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13618/direct-access-to-askubuntu-reputation-statistics) which don't provide sufficient information.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's brilliant and the answer :)